# position.coords.latitude not working in ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

In ionic, i am using cordovaGeoLocation Plugin to get users location.

```
position.coords.latitude;
```

Network Monitor says :

```
getCurrentPosition() requires https connection
```

Above code is not working in android device, debugging network packets says, that it requires **https** as all lib and js files are loaded locally from ionic, how ssl can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using the plugin correctly. You should be querying the position after 'device ready' with this piece of code.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                         [geolocationError],
                                         [geolocationOptions]);
```

Then catch the position it passes back

```
function geolocationSuccess(position){
     //position.coords.latitude
}
```

Comment: It's working here and this is from the docs so you are doing something wrong. Also your code in your OP is bad.